# Applying for a job as a PhD student

Tags: phd, job

I started my PhD upon the acceptance to my current university because this got so many people excited about me, and I didn't want to disappoint them. I finished my PhD coursework with excellent marks, and I made speedy progress in my research which made my PhD supervisor very happy. However, my supervisor's research area is not something that I want to work in for the rest of my life and I got depressed because as a PhD student, I am working so hard, day and night, towards the outcome that I don't really want. I am currently in 2nd year of my PhD program.

I expressed this to my supervisor and he told me that he doesn't want me to make spontaneous decisions since I am doing so well in my PhD program and that I am making a speedy progress. My supervisor suggested me to take 4 month medical leave, and I took that offer.

However, more I think of my issue more I want to pursue my dream of working in Clinical Research Organization (CRO) as a statistician/statistical programmer. Over the break, I have successfully acquired industry professional certifications that CRO firms often look for, and I am ready to apply for entry-level jobs at CRO firm. I am still on the medical leave from my PhD program, although the leave is almost over (note: my medical leave is unpaid leave. All my TA/RA/Scholarship funding has been suspended during my medical leave).

When I resume my academic program in January (a new semester), I actually have no intention to continue in the PhD program. I will be applying for the job at CRO firms, and if I get a job I am intending to quit.

I am wondering whether I should just tell my PhD supervisor about my feelings/plans and quit the PhD program before I apply for any jobs? or should I remain as a PhD student even though I am not intending to stay in the program, until I get an actual job offer?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you completely committed to leaving the PhD program? Not my field, but it seems like a career in clinical research would benefit from a PhD, even if the PhD isn't in the exact area you want to pursue long-term.

Comment: Also: is there any way to switch into a terminal master's track?

Comment: Hello, in my country, a Master's degree is a requirement before entering a PhD program. So as a PhD student, I already have my Master's degree.

Comment: The job I am intending to apply for is statistical programmer positions, which only requires master's degree in my field.

Comment: To me, I think that stay on PhD program while applying jobs just complicates the issues even more, as if I stay in the PhD program, I will be receiving TA/RA funding from my department as well as the government scholarship for being a full-time PhD student, so if I find an employment then I am not sure how these issues would sort out.

Comment: Get a new job first, then quit.

Comment: Thanks for info. I understand the job you're currently applying for doesn't need a PhD, but I think you should also consider the opportunities you might want to pursue 10+ years from now (the answer might well be the same, but it 's something to consider). At any rate, your actual question seems to be covered by [Leaving PhD program to apply for industry job - better to apply while still officially enrolled?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25770) and/or [How to tell my advisor that I am quitting my PhD...](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66248).

Comment: Why would you leave before having a new job?